# Trigger lambda function daily at a given time

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-lambda, cronexpression

I have a lambda function setup and tested via manual triggers. I want this function to run once every day at mid-day.

To achieve this I created a new *CloudWatch Events - Schedule* trigger with a Schedule expression of `cron(0 12 ? * * *)`.

With the function and trigger enabled, the function was not invoked. What should the correct Schedule expression be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cron expression was correct. Remember that your AWS region may not be in the same timezone and adjust your expectations accordingly.

Comment: Yup, it defaults to UTC